# Getting "Permission Denied" response while using ImgurAPI

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, imgur

I'm using this code to get data about an Imgur Image. I assume this doesn't require Oauth2 excepts the client ID in the header.

```
import requests
client_id = '<my_client_id>'
header = {"Authorization": "Client-ID " + client_id};

r = requests.post("https://api.imgur.com/3/image/WPYW1pE", headers=header);
r = r.json();
print(r);
```

However, I'm receiving "Permission Denied" error. Does it require access_token or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using requests.get instead of requests.post solved the issue. Fixed code.

```
import requests
client_id = '<my_client_id>'
header = {"Authorization": "Client-ID " + client_id};

r = requests.get("https://api.imgur.com/3/image/WPYW1pE", headers=header);
r = r.json();
print(r);
```